# Attribute is not allowed admin Magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute

I am not able to edit the product area in admin. I am getting the following error -

```
Element 'fieldset', attribute 'sortOrder': The attribute 'sortOrder' is not allowed.
```

I have cleared cache and it worked twice. I am not sure if the issue is for cache or something else. Exception.log is not showing anything.

Comment: Have you done any customization in product_form.xml in any of you modules?

Comment: This site I have not built it came to me like this. So I do not have a starting point